# Failed to build gem native extension installing p4ruby Net::ReadTimeout with #<Socket:fd 9> (Net::ReadTimeout)

Tags: linux, rubygems, rvm, perforce, rhel7

I´m trying to install the p4ruby gem on our RHEL 7.9 server and I keep getting the "failed to build gem native extension" error.

Here is what the log contains this message:

> have_library: checking for -lsupc++... -------------------- no

I have installed the Development Tools with

> yum group install "Development tools"

And I´m using RVM with Ruby Version 2.7.1.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Thanks to Knud Larsens hint

> yum install gcc-c++ libstdc++-static

fixed the previous issue.

But the building still doesn´t work

> `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout with #<Socket:fd 9> (Net::ReadTimeout)

is what I get now.

Comment: `yum install gcc-c++ libstdc++-static` .... provides `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libsupc++.a`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the error for not finding libsupc++, but it still throws `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout with #<Socket:fd 9> (Net::ReadTimeout). I edited the original question.